# Exception handling, If Statements or Try/Catch blocks?

Tags: java, exception, for-loop, try-catch

Which way is better for exception handling in your opinion, `if` statements or `Try/Catch` blocks?

Because, as you know, all exceptions can handled with `if` statements.

Comment: That Was a bit mistake, Edited

Comment: probably what @APoliteBoy meant is All the exceptions can be handled using `If` statements ?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the same exception handled by a `try catch` and an `if` statement?

Comment: if you can use an `if` statement to avoid causing an exception to happen, than you probably should do so.  But sometimes you don't have that option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the situation. I'll try to explain.

Consider this simple example:

```
try {
  myVar.myFunc();
} 
catch(NullPointerException e) {
  //bla bla
}
```

**OR**

```
if (myVar != null) 
   myVar.myFunc();
```

If `myVar` can be `null` as part of your code flow, then you can use `if` statement, otherwise you should use the exception, because it probably caused because of things that were not under your control.

Answer (score 0):

Well, From what I understand you mean with if/else statements that the return values of functions will be SUCCESS or FAILURE, and all actual work will be done on the arguments of the function.

This is a C style coding - where there were no exceptions.

In java, because you cannot pass elements by references (or pointers) this approach is problematic (You will have to create a wrapper for a method that returns an `int`, very non-elegant), and even in C - it is more of a necessety then something elegant.

Example - a C style code can do:

```
int calcSomething(int arg1, int arg2, int* result) { 
  //calcualtions
  if (...) return FAILURE;
  *result = ...
  return SUCCESS;
}
```

And the coding environment will be:

```
if (calcSomething(...) == FAILURE) { handleError(); }
```

Note - the approach did not completely diasppear in java, for example [`Collection#add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29) returns a `boolean` that indicates if the operation succeeded or not. It is mostly used for operations where the `false` value is not really an error - more of an indication that there is nothing to do.

Whenever the "error" is blocking - use exceptions for error handling - they are much more readable and allows better maintainability of your code. If it is just an indication (for eaxmple - element already is in the set) - a boolean in return value can be just fine.